# How to set custom value in Angular text interpolation

Tags: angular

Is it possible to set a value with data that is being interpolated in Angular?

Template:

```
{{ this.weatherData?.forecast[customValue].hourly[0].weather_code }}
```

TS:

```
customValue = 1;
```

End result would be *forecast = 1*

Comment: Yes, you just did? What is the problem if there is one?

Comment: can u give another example please, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
forecast = {{ this.weatherData?.forecast[customValue].hourly[0].weather_code }}
```

or

```
{{ 'forecast = ' + this.weatherData?.forecast[customValue].hourly[0].weather_code }}
```

Both will work